# Prove that "$\sigma_n(S,t)\ge 0$ for infinitely many $n$'s" is enough for a series being a Fourier-Stieltjes series of a positive measure

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

**Lemma 7.5**(Katznelson's book on harmonic analysis) A series $S\sim\sum a_ne^{int}$ is the Fourier-Stieltjes series of a positive measure if, and only if, for all $n$ and $t\in\mathbb T$,
$$
\sigma_n(S,t)=\sum_{-n}^n(1-|j|/(n+1))a_je^{ijt}\ge 0.
$$
The proof is rather strightforward, but the author remarked that the condition "$\sigma_n(S,t)\ge 0$ for all $n$" can clearly be replaced by "$\sigma_n(S,t)\ge 0$ for infinitely many $n$'s".

I cannot figure out the reason why we can weaken the premise.

Note that we have $\sigma_n(S,t)\ge 0$ for infinitely many $n$ such that
$$ \|\sigma_n(S)\|_{M(\mathbb T)}=\frac 1{2\pi}\int\sigma_n(S,t)dt=a_0 .$$
So in order to use Corollary 7.3, we shall try to argue $\|\sigma_n(S)\|\le C$ for all $n$ where $C$ is a constant. Any suggestion?

---

The same lemma is also discussed under:[Fourier Stieltjes series of a positive measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3229456/497335) but I have a different question.

---

**Addendum**:

Proof of Lemma 7.5:

If $S=S(\mu)$ for a positive $\mu\in M(\mathbb T)$ and if $f\in C(\mathbb T)$ is non-negative, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int f(t)\overline{\sigma_n (S,t)}dt=\sum_{-n}^n\left( 1-\frac{|j|}{n+1} \right)\hat f(j)\overline{\hat\mu(j)}=\int\sigma_n(f)\overline{d\mu}\ge 0
$$
since $\mu\ge 0$ and, by 3.1, $\sigma_n(f,t)>0$. Since this is true for arbitrary nonnegative $f$, $\sigma_n(S,t)\ge 0$ on $\mathbb T$. Assuming $\sigma_n(S,t)\ge 0$ we obtain
$$
\|\sigma_n(S)\|_{M(\mathbb T)}=\frac 1{2\pi}\int \sigma_n(S,t)dt=a_0
$$
and, by Corollary 7.3, $S=S(\mu)$ for some $\mu\in M(\mathbb T)$. For arbitrary nonnegative $f\in C(\mathbb T)$, $\int f d\mu=\lim_{n\to\infty}1/2\pi \int f(t)\sigma_n(S,t) dt\ge 0$ and it follows that $\mu$ is a positive measure. Q.E.D.

Comment: it looks like we read a lot of the same books. does the proof of Lemma 7.5 work for infinitely many $n$ instead of all $n$? I don't know what you're talking about when you start saying "though we have..." (which is written grammatically incorrectly).

Comment: @mathworker21 Sorry for the ambiguity, I have included the whole proof. In fact, I am trying to learn the elements of Fourier analysis since I find it a very powerful tool in ergodic theory which I am also interested in.